# Fill CardView inside screen area

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-cardview

In my android app, I am a fragment in which I want to display to CardViews. These both CardViews should fill entire screen area. The image which is shown inside the cardview element is very large image and the same should be shrinked to display inside cardview. I am not able to fill entire area of screen with following code and make cardview clickable.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.myFirstApp.app1.cardviewFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <!--<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" ></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>-->
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" android:background="@color/colorAccent">
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/card_view1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp">

            <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/display_card_view_linearLayout1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/display_name1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:text="@string/app_name"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                    android:paddingTop="8dp"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:background="#1976D2"/>
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/display_image1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/action_settings"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/display_information1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:text="Card View Footer"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/display_image1"
                    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                    android:paddingTop="8dp"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:background="#1976D2"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/card_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp">

            <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/display_card_view_linearLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/display_name2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:text="@string/app_name"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                    android:paddingTop="8dp"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:background="#1976D2"/>
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/display_image2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/action_settings"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/display_information2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:text="Card View Footer"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/display_image2"
                    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                    android:paddingTop="8dp"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:background="#1976D2"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

How I can make both CardView fill entire area and make them clickable?

Thanks in advance,

*IamHuM*

Answer (score 0):

try put this in cardview:

```
android:layout_margin="0dp"
```

i not have idea if this work for you but in one of my apps it worked you can se the code here [GitHub code](https://github.com/brunomassa/LuxVilla) in the settings activity layout, i use a full width cardview.

Comment: I suggest you expand your answer to include an explanation of why this should work.

Comment: i not have idea if this work for you but in one of my apps it worked you can se the code here [GitHub code](https://github.com/brunomassa/LuxVilla) in the settings activity layout, i use a full width cardview.

Comment: okay, so please merge your comment into your answer (click "edit").